# Add Top Left Right rounded border to pdfpcell in itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

```
`cb.RoundRectangle(

         rect.Left + 0f,
         rect.Bottom + 0f,
         rect.Width - 0,
         rect.Height - 0, 4

        );`
```

i want to add round curve to cell top right border not bottom

Comment: You need to look at the source code of the `RoundRectangle()` method and copy it in such a way that only the top-left and top-right border are rounded. Is that a problem?

Comment: i am trying to round the top left right border but this code is round all the corner  please help how can i round to border only